# Different ways to create classes?

Tags: java, class, object, netbeans

I've been practicing making GUI in netbeans and came across this auto generated code

```
  saveButton.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                saveButtonMousePressed(evt);
            }
```

I'm just confused in the argument "new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter()". I know that when we use the "new" keyword we make an object of that class. But after that "new" statement it declared a method so my perception was that "an object with a method? I know we create object so that we can use methods not create a method within them".

After researching and reading about Inner Classes, I now have a different perspective.

***Would that be possible to create a class in a argument with the "new" statement? if true then that code didn't created a object, but instead created a class.***

If my conclusion would be right there are 2 ways (I know so far) to create classes in java.

1. by using,

   ```
   public clas Sample() {

   //insert methods here

   }
   ```
2. and by using,

   ```
   public void getSomething(new Sample() { //insert method here })
   ```

Did I get this one right? I'm just a beginner in java(Self Study).

Comment: I can't quite tell what you're asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a different way to create a `class`, actually you define it in the same way you would with any other class but you don't name it, it is just a specialized `MouseAdapter`.

What actually happens is that you define a specialized version of `mousePressed` without the need to associate it to a named subclass of `MouseAdapter`. It's like defining and using the class in the same point. You define a specific class with specific behavior and instantiate it.

Indeed that's called an [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html). This has nothing in common with an [inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html), which is a class that is defined inside another class (so they are nested).

Comment: Actually, an anonymous class defined at an instance-level, i.e., not in static field declarations, methods, or blocks, will behaves like an inner class of the instance it is created by. Therefore, it has access to the outer class instance's methods and fields. When there is ambiguity you can use `Outer.this.someMethod()`.